# Not importing pymysql but has "pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server"

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask, pymysql

In flask, I planned to use MySQL, hence: 
    `from flaskext.mysql import MySQL`

However, when I ran the flask app, I have the below error:

`pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xx.x.xx:xxxx' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)")`

The thing is, I'm not even planning to use pymysql in the first place. While I do have that package installed, I'm not importing it, so why is the error related to pymysql?

I'm a beginner in flask and am continuing a prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Flask-MySql requires PyMySQL as a dependency.  It's imported by Flask-MySQL [here](https://github.com/cyberdelia/flask-mysql/blob/master/flaskext/mysql.py#L3).  As for the error, either MySQL isn't running, or you've misconfigured the Flask-MySQL extension to look for it in the wrong place.  Make sure that you've configured it properly, with the correct MySQL server settings as shown [here](https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#configuration).

Comment: I'm actually using sqlalchemy to listen to the mysql database:

```app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql: xxx'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False```

That's why I didn't configure the MySQL settings according to the link you gave. Do I need to import pymysql even though I'm using sqlalchemy?

Comment: So, that looks like config for Flask-SQLAlchemy.  If that's what you're using, then you don't need Flask-MySQL at all.  You should be using something like `from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy` instead of  `from flaskext.mysql import MySQL`.